# Can Not Use Twitter Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am implement Authentication for Twitter by ASP.NET MVC.

```
app.UseTwitterAuthentication(new TwitterAuthenticationOptions()
{
       ConsumerKey = "XXX",
       ConsumerSecret = "XXX",
});
```

When I clicked the link http://localhost:55586/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F
I met a error as below image:
I don't know I missed somethings or not.
[[image]]

Comment: Can you provide full stack trace? I think somewhat message like "Unable to create to obtain configuration from XXX" may written there.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I updated image

Comment: I advise you to post the full stack trace as text, it is easier to read. At this time it still not show all text including possible "Unable to create..." message I want to see with.

Comment: By the way, I think it's a bit dangerous to put the ConsumerKey and ConsumerSecret here.

Comment: @User2012384 Thanks for reminding me. It's just a sample for demonstration.

Comment: for third party authentications, you need to use https i.e ssl, is that what you're using for your project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Thank you, everyone.
Finally, I found a solution.**

**Step 1:**

```
app.UseTwitterAuthentication(new TwitterAuthenticationOptions()
{
    ConsumerKey = "XXX",
    ConsumerSecret = "XXX",
    BackchannelCertificateValidator = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.CertificateSubjectKeyIdentifierValidator(new[]
    {
       "A5EF0B11CEC04103A34A659048B21CE0572D7D47", // VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G2
       "0D445C165344C1827E1D20AB25F40163D8BE79A5", // VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3
       "7FD365A7C2DDECBBF03009F34339FA02AF333133", // VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
       "39A55D933676616E73A761DFA16A7E59CDE66FAD", // Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
       "‎add53f6680fe66e383cbac3e60922e3b4c412bed", // Symantec Class 3 EV SSL CA - G3
       "4eb6d578499b1ccf5f581ead56be3d9b6744a5e5", // VeriSign Class 3 Primary CA - G5
       "5168FF90AF0207753CCCD9656462A212B859723B", // DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server C‎A 
       "B13EC36903F8BF4701D498261A0802EF63642BC3" // DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
     }),
});
```

Run the project again. I met the error as below:
[image]

**Step 2:**

> https://apps.twitter.com/
> Go to the Settings Tab Set a Callback URL
> to any website.  Even if it is not real
>
> => I set it to http://google.com
> [image]

Then, It works for me. I don't know why I need to set Callback URL. After I set any value into it, I cannot set empty value. So, I think it's an error of Twitter API.

[asp-net-mvc-5-owin-twitter-auth-throwing-401-exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21651211/asp-net-mvc-5-owin-twitter-auth-throwing-401-exception)